# Swift create socket client with GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

How to create a socket client with GCDAsyncSocket using swift langauge.
I use following code:

```
class MySocketClient: GCDAsyncSocketDelegate{
let addr = "192.168.131.218"
let port :UInt16 = 8000
var inp :NSInputStream?
var out :NSOutputStream?
var bsocket: GCDAsyncSocket!
var err :NSError?

func initClient(name: String) ->String{
    bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    return "init result:"+name
}

func connect(){
    if(!bsocket.connectToHost(addr, onPort: port, error: nil)){
        println("Error.")
    }else{
        println("Connecting...")

    }
}
}
```

But it is strange, the result of

> bsocket.connectToHost(addr, onPort: port, error: nil)
>   always return true.

No matter I change the ip address or port which are not available.

Why? And what is the right way to create a socket client, and use it to receive/send data to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectToHost` returns true because the connection attempt has started successfully.

When the connection is made, the delegate method `socket:didConnectToHost:port:` will be called.

From the documentation for `connectToHost`:

> This method will return NO if an error is detected, and set the error
>   pointer (if one was given). Possible errors would be a nil host,
>   invalid interface, or socket is already connected.
>
> If no errors are detected, this method will start a background connect
>   operation and immediately return YES. The delegate callbacks are used
>   to notify you when the socket connects, or if the host was
>   unreachable.